# Models of ZF intermediate between a model of ZFC and a generic extension

Tags: set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice

Let $M$ be a countable model of $ZFC$ and $M[G]$ be a (set) generic extension of $M$. Suppose $N$ is a countable model of $ZF$ with

$$M\subseteq N \subseteq M[G]$$

and that $N=M(x)$ for some $x\in N$; i.e., it is the smallest inner model of $M[G]$ which contains $x$ and $M$.

Is $N$ a symmetric extension of $M$?

Comment: The answer is no! For a rather dramatic example, see for instance [MR3878470](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3878470) Karagila, Asaf *[The Bristol model: an abyss called a Cohen real](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06939)*. J. Math. Log. **18** (2018), no. 2, 1850008, 37 pp. (Take a look at section 7.2 for a brief comment on this matter.)

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this result and had it in mind, but I'm not sure it does answer the question. This is why I added the condition that M[G] is a generic extension of M. Grigorieff's Theorem B shows that in such a case N=M[x] for some x \in N. If I understand the remarks on the Bristol model correctly, then it cannot be of the form M[x] (assuming that L=M). I probably should have mentioned the Theorem B think in the OP.

Comment: Toby, a Cohen real is the most basic of generic extensions...

Comment: Hmmm .. I'll edit the question and see if you still think it's solved. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @Toby I edited $M[x]$ to $M(x)$. In modern notation, the former is by design a model of choice, so it would be confusing to use it in this setting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if $N=M(x)$ (taking the modern notation over Grigorieff's $M[x]$), then it is a symmetric extension. This is a very recent result of Toshimichi Usuba (see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00895) and [that](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10246)).

However, by the Bristol model construction, this symmetric extension need not be obtained by the forcing that was used to get $M[G]$.

Comment: The Bristol model is pretty intimidating. Can you elaborate a little on your second comment? Happy to move to email if that is preferable.

Comment: The point is that $L(V_\alpha^M)$ where $M$ is the Bristol model are all symmetric models.

Comment: But regardless, feel free to drop me an email if you have any followups or any other choiceless questions...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have a question. In Grigorieff's *Intermediate submodels and generic extensions in set theory* he proves that every symmetric submodel of $M[G]$ is of the form $(\mathsf{HOD} (M(x)))^{M[G]}$ for some $x \in M[G]$ (Theorem C), and then he observes that every inner model of this kind is equal to $M(y)$ for some $y \in M[G]$ with $y\subset M$ (Corollary 2, Section 9). Thus every $M(y)$ for some $y \in M[G]$ with $y\subset M$ is a symmetric extension of $M$. The novelty of Usuba's result is that $M(y)$ is a symmetric extension of $M$ even when $y$ is not a subset of $M$?

Comment: @Lorenzo Send me an email. This question has a long answer.